# Install from ISO on Boot (CentOS 7)

Tags: centos, grub2

I have an ISO that lives at `/temp/simp.iso` and I want to install this software on CentOS 7.

Here is my current `/etc/grub.d/40_custom` file:

```
menuentry "install SIMP" {
    set isofile="/temp/simp.iso"
    loopback loop (hd0,1)$isofile }
```

Then I run `grub2-mkconfig -o`

Nothing happens on reboot and the software is not installed. What am I missing?

Comment: What software are you trying to install? Why do you need to do it at boot and not from within the OS?

Comment: I am trying to install SIMP (https://www.simp-project.com/) and the instructions say: "Install as follows: Boot the system using the SIMP ISO" (https://simp.readthedocs.io/en/master/getting_started_guide/Installation_Options/ISO/Installing_SIMP_From_An_ISO.html)

Comment: Did my answer help or do you need more information?

Comment: No, all you did was copy the link I already provided to the docs... I also read the docs and my problem is that the system does not restart automatically and even upon manual restart SIMP is not installed.

Answer (score 0):

Burn the ISO to a USB, CD/DVD. Use something like `dd if=/path/to/iso of=/dev/path/to/disk`. Then just boot the system to that media no need from messing with grub, follow the installer, making sure to point it to the right drives and everything. From what I understand from reading the docs, the system should restart automatically. It should now be installed and you should change the default passwords.

To boot to the ISO: Go into the BIOS and change the first boot device to your USB, CD/DVD.

Complete instruction: [Here](https://simp.readthedocs.io/en/master/getting_started_guide/Installation_Options/ISO/index.html)